# Handling page header in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, yeoman

I am trying to make a simple app using Ember.js. I am using `yeoman ember`.

I have following application template

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<div class="content">{{outlet}}</div>
```

I have a few routes defined. Now what I am not being able to do is, find a way to update the text inside `<h1>` for different routes. For example,

if I navigate to `/#/users` I need it to change to `Users`.
if I navigate to `/#/users/1` I need it to change to the model's firstname.

I tried this in ApplicationRoute

```
setupController: function(controller){
    controller.set('title', 'Dashboard');
}
```

and changing to `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`
but it only works for `ApplicationRoute` and no other route!

```
setupController: function(controller){
    controller.set('title', 'Users');
}
```

This does not work in UsersRoute. Even the output of the route disappears.

What is the right approach to get this to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you simply create an action in ApplicationRoute that sets the title as passed to it as an argument, and then have your sub route call that action in setupController. That should do the trick.
So in you application route:

```
//in application route 
actions:{
    updatePageTitle: function(title){
        this.controllerFor('application').set('title', title);
    }
}
```

And in your individual child route:

```
setupController:function(controller, model){
    this.send('updatePageTitle', model.get('something'));
    this._super(controller, model);
}
```

Comment: Well the title worked.. But adding `setupController` in the user route, makes all the model disappear!!

Comment: Updated my answer, you must also call the _super in setupController or else manually set model to the controller. Hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: hmmm.. now it worked.. Seems too lot to do for such a small requirement!! :)